# How to bind daterangepicker, start date and end date, to datatables ajax data

Tags: ajax, datatables, bootstrap-daterangepicker

I have a datatable for data presentation and a daterangepicker for selecting the daterange shown in the datatable. I get tge data with an ajax call. At initialization everything is fine, I get the data for the inital daterange selected

```
"ajax": {
                "url": "/api/ajax", // ajax source
                data: function (d) {
                    d.startDate = $('#reportrange').data(daterangepicker).startDate.format('DD.MM.YYYY');
                    d.endDate = $('#reportrange').data(daterangepicker).endDate.format('DD.MM.YYYY');

                },
```

But if I want get a new date range, the old range doesn't  change
How can I read the new daterange a get it to datatables ajax

Here the complete code so far

```
$('#reportrange').daterangepicker({

            startDate: moment().subtract('days', 29),
            endDate: moment(),

            ranges: {
                'Today': [moment(), moment()],
                'Yesterday': [moment().subtract('days', 1), moment().subtract('days', 1)],
                'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract('days', 6), moment()],
                'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract('days', 29), moment()],
                'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
                'Last Month': [moment().subtract('month', 1).startOf('month'), moment().subtract('month', 1).endOf('month')]
            },
            buttonClasses: ['btn'],
            applyClass: 'green',
            cancelClass: 'default',
            format: 'DD.MM.YYYY',
            separator: ' to ',

        },
        function (start, end) {
            $('#reportrange span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));

        }
    );
    //Set the initial state of the picker label
    $('#reportrange span').html(moment().subtract('days', 29).format('DD.MM.YYYY') + ' - ' + moment().format('DD.MM.YYYY'));



    var oTable = $('#sample_1').DataTable({


        buttons: [
            {
                extend: 'print',
                className: 'btn dark btn-outline',
                exportOptions: {columns: [0, 1, 2, 3]}
            },
            {
                extend: 'pdf', className: 'btn dark btn-outline',
                download: 'open',
                exportOptions: {columns: [0, 1, 2, 3]}
            },
            {
                extend: 'csv',
                className: 'btn dark btn-outline ',
                exportOptions: {columns: [0, 1, 2, 3]}
            },

        ],



        "order": [
            [0, 'desc']
        ],

        "lengthMenu": [
            [5, 10, 15, 20, -1],
            [5, 10, 15, 20, "All"] // change per page values here
        ],
        // set the initial value
        "pageLength": 5,
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": {
            "url": "/api/ajax", // ajax source
            "data": function (d) {
                d.startDate = $('#reportrange').data(daterangepicker).startDate.format('DD.MM.YYYY');
                d.endDate = $('#reportrange').data(daterangepicker).endDate.format('DD.MM.YYYY');

            },
        },



        "dom": "<'row' <'col-md-12'B>><'row'<'col-md-6 col-sm-12'l><'col-md-6 col-sm-12'f>r><'table-scrollable't><'row'<'col-md-5 col-sm-12'i><'col-md-7 col-sm-12'p>>",
        "bSortClasses": false,
        // Uncomment below line("dom" parameter) to fix the dropdown overflow issue in the datatable cells. The default datatable layout
        // setup uses scrollable div(table-scrollable) with overflow:auto to enable vertical scroll(see: assets/global/plugins/datatables/plugins/bootstrap/dataTables.bootstrap.js).
        // So when dropdowns used the scrollable div should be removed.
        //"dom": "<'row' <'col-md-12'T>><'row'<'col-md-6 col-sm-12'l><'col-md-6 col-sm-12'f>r>t<'row'<'col-md-5 col-sm-12'i><'col-md-7 col-sm-12'p>>",
    });

    $('#reportrange').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev) {


        oTable.draw();
        ev.preventDefault();

    });
```